# Backbone on JSON nested structure: use single Model to manipulate whole structure

Tags: json, backbone.js

I've the following JSON structure:

```
{
"Results": {
    "Package": [{
        "@ID": "a1a2a3a4",
        "Name": "Package Name",
        "Category_ID": {
            "@Product_Line_ID": "11",
            "#text": "11"
        },
        "Effective_Start_Date": "2013-08-09",
        "Available_Start_Date": "2013-08-09",
        "Product_Name": "Web National Promotion",
        "Product_To_Product": [{
            "@ID": "b1b2b3b4",
            "Association_Start_Date": "2013-08-09",
            "Max_Occurs": "1",
            "Min_Occurs": "1",
            "Product": [{
                "@ID": "a5a6a7a8",
                "Name": "Product Name 1",
                "Effective_Start_Date": "2013-08-05",
                "Available_Start_Date": "2013-08-05"
                },{
                "@ID": "a5a6a7a8",
                "Name": "Product Name 2",
                "Effective_Start_Date": "2013-08-05",
                "Available_Start_Date": "2013-08-05"
                etc............
```

I would not create a complex structure of Model, Relation, Collection etc. (This JSON has a complex structure of nested elements

Package
 - Product_to_Product
   -- Product 
   -- Procutct etc.
 - Charge_to_Carge
   -- Charge
   -- Charge
etc...

I would like to know if there is a way to create a single instance of Backbonde, for example for "Package" node, and access from that to the other childs and information.

Please, show me your possibile solution to manage this complex structure and a possibile wasy (code) to access from Model "Package" to the internal childs.

Thank you

Charls

Answer (score 0):

Creating Backbone model with any nested structure is as simple as :

```
var Package = Backbone.Model.extend();
var package = new Package({
        "@ID": "a1a2a3a4",
        "Name": "Package Name",
        "Category_ID": {
            "@Product_Line_ID": "11",
            "#text": "11"
        },
        "Effective_Start_Date": "2013-08-09",
        "Available_Start_Date": "2013-08-09",
        "Product_Name": "Web National Promotion",
        "Product_To_Product": [] // might have nested objects
});
package.get("Name"); // Package Name
package.get("Category_ID").get("#text"); // TypeError: no get method found
```

But, the only advantage you would get out of this is using Backbone.Model APIs and Events on the direct attributes (`@ID`, `Name`, `Category_ID`, etc and not `@Product_Line_ID`, `#text`) of your model. So accessing inner objects of your model would be similar to the way you access your javascript objects.

If you really have a meaningful structure for your model with some relationship(say one to many relationship between Package and Products) defined then I would suggest you to look at some Backbone extensions, they would really help you. One such extension is [Backbone Associations](http://dhruvaray.github.io/backbone-associations/).

Comment: Thank Niranjan for your reply. I have to call an api service (REST) that returns me a JSON structure. would it be possible to create a single backbone model loading and fetching data from this url and manage the child nodes? It's manageble like a javascript object?

Comment: Yes, it is perfectly possible to create singe model with the response JSON. To manage child nodes(inner nested properties e.g. `#text`) you'll have to access them as : `package.get("Category_ID")["#text"]`.